# Tomcat 8 Changing Configuration and Webapp Folder

Tags: tomcat

I'm seeking a way of changing the default Tomcat configuration and webapp directory, so i can move all the configuration files on a separate folder. and all java code files in other folder, And somehow to pass that on the tomcat service.

Does anybody know a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Read the `RUNNING.txt` file that comes with Tomcat, especially this section:

```
==================================================
Advanced Configuration - Multiple Tomcat Instances
==================================================
```

This is what you are looking for.

Note that you can deploy application WAR files (or exploded WAR-like directories) anywhere you want by dropping an XML deployment descriptor into `conf/[engine]/[host]/[appname].xml`. Just put the full path to the WAR file (or exploded WAR-like directory) into the `docBase` attribute of your `<Context>` element.

Comment: What about changing the configuration File folder, so it can load the config files from different folder

Comment: Different from what folder?

Comment: Lets say i have tomcat placed on K:/DevEnv/Tomcat so essentially the config file is placed on K:/DevEnv/Tomcat/conf

Comment: I would like to place it on K:/DevEnv/configs/Tomcat